How to parse font file using the PDFBox library
I need to load a PDF document get all the embedded fonts, and parse them, but I have some issue when I try to parse fonts from font.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile3() I get an exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 'head' table is mandatory
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:110)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:175)

Here is my code for parsing the PDF resources:
try (PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(path2))) {
            final int numberOfPages = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int pageId = 0; pageId < numberOfPages; pageId++) {
                final PDPage page = pdf.getPage(pageId);
                final PDResources pageResources = page.getResources();

                final Iterable<COSName> fontNames = pageResources.getFontNames();
                for (COSName fontResource : fontNames) {
                    final String fontName = fontResource.getName();
                    final PDFont font = pageResources.getFont(fontResource);
                    final PDStream fontFile2 = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile3();
                    final TTFParser ttfParser = new TTFParser(true);
                    final TrueTypeFont font1 = ttfParser.parse(fontFile2.createInputStream());
                    final byte[] encoded = font.encode("A");
                    System.out.println("FONT_NAME: " + fontName);
                    System.out.println("FONT: " + font.getName());
                }
            }
        }

AFMParser doesn't work too.
AFMParser afmParser = new AFMParser(fontFile2.createInputStream());
final FontMetrics parse = afmParser.parse(true);

This  font from adobe reader hasn't been parsed.
Can anyone help me with this issue? How to parse fonts from fontFile3?

It's tricky, not all fonts are TrueType fonts.

@TilmanHausherr maybe you know how to parse another type of fonts using pdfbox library?

This is a rather complex matter, read the PDF specification and look at the actual type of the PDFont object.
